# How to sum and group values using MySQL ?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sum

I was wondering how to sum and group values using MySQL. Now thats simple, however I have a bit of an odd situation.

I have a table that allows users to insert the amount of cigaretes smoked every day, what I am trying to do is sum the data for every day .

Anybody has any ideas how with php or mysql I could sum the data of cigaretes smoked per day and group it by day ?

Comment: Table Schema would be required for exact solution

Comment: You'll need to show the table (and some example data) or it's impossible to answer in a concise way.

Comment: @Gregor Post the table schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    SUM(how_many) AS per_day,
    `date`
FROM
    cigaretes
GROUP BY
    DATE(`date`)
```