# How to sum all visits from mySQL and show it for each id like a group?

Tags: mysql

My mySQL look like this

```
id visits
3   0
3   0
3   1
4   1
4   1
4   0
2   1
```

How can I have something more like group for all my entries id :

```
id visits
3   1
4   2
2   1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sum and group values using MySQL ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680920/how-to-sum-and-group-values-using-mysql)

Comment: have you done any research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(visits) as visit FROM YOURTABLE GROUP BY ID;
```

[SQLFIDDEL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1292/2) is here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Group By` Clause

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Visits) FROM YOURTABLE GROUP BY ID;
```